# Datasource connection pooling for CORDA V3

Tags: datasource, connection-pooling, corda

When configuring a JDBC Datasource in the configuration file for CORDA, could a database connection pool be used such as the Apache Commons connection pool used on Java application servers? Would this even provide any advantage since CORDA itself might be providing object pooling for the node?

Answer (score 0):

Corda already uses HikariPool so it wouldn't provide an advantage